# Mobile app (MAUI Blazor) authentication (Google, Apple, Facebook) with backend api (.Net Core Web API)

Tags: google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi, maui

I am quite new to the mobile world and not familiar with how it should be set up correctly.
I've done some research and found out what I could but I am stuck now and not sure how to proceed.
My current findings with some code:

- I am using .NET MAUI Blazor for the mobile apps development
- The back-end that (should?) handle the database calls and the authentication from the mobile users is made using .NET Core Web API
- Database back-end is a Cosmos DB

I've tested the back-end connection to Cosmos DB, and it is working fine (using the sample weather forecast in VS)

I have the .NET MAUI Blazor app now, where I would like to add the Google primarily then afterwards Apple and Facebook authentication but I have few questions on the implementation:

- What is the flow between the mobile app, the service provider and the back-end ?
- How do I register users using this kind of authentication ?
- How is the login process ? Entirely on the mobile and the token is shared with the back-end or something else ?
- Where do I keep the token I believe that I will receive back from the provider ? both mobile & server side (Web API)?

For the code, you can imagine that the .NET MAUI Blazor is the base template, I've messed way too much and managed to break it so I am just starting from the base on this one.

For the .NET Core Web API here is the code that I have so far (mostly for testing purpose and understand how features works):

Program.cs

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using System.Diagnostics;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Set environment variable
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID", "xxx");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID", "xxx");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET", "xxx");

var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri"));
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Print the configuration
foreach (var setting in builder.Configuration.AsEnumerable())
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Key: {setting.Key}, Value: {setting.Value}");
}

// Create a new SecretClient using the DefaultAzureCredential
var secretClient = new SecretClient(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Retrieve the secret
var secret = await secretClient.GetSecretAsync("xxx");

// Initialize the Cosmos DB client
CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(secret.Value.Value);

// Add the Cosmos DB client as a singleton service
builder.Services.AddSingleton(cosmosClient);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

WeatherForecast.cs

```
namespace MiddlewareAPI.DataModel
{
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public string id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

WeatherForecastController.cs

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using MiddlewareAPI.DataModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace MiddlewareAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly string _mySecret;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        private readonly CosmosClient _cosmosClient;
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
{
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        public WeatherForecastController(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, CosmosClient cosmosClient)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _logger = logger;
            _cosmosClient = cosmosClient;


            try
            {
                var kvUri = _configuration["VaultUri"];

                var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
                var secret = client.GetSecretAsync("xxx");

                _mySecret = secret.Result.Value.Value;
                Debug.WriteLine($"MySecret constructor: {_mySecret}");

            }
            catch (Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to authenticate with Azure AD.");
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"Failed to retrieve the secret from Azure Key Vault. Status code: {ex.Status}, Error message: {ex.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An unknown error occurred while trying to retrieve the CosmosDb connection string.");
            }

        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] WeatherForecast forecast)
        {
            if (forecast == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("The forecast object cannot be null.");
            }
            string forecastJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(forecast);
            Debug.WriteLine($"\nforecast json: {forecastJson}\n");
            try
            {
                // Get a reference to the database and container
                Database database = null;
                try
                {
                    database = _cosmosClient.GetDatabase("xxx");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while trying to get the database.");
                    return StatusCode(500, "An error occurred while trying to get the database.");
                }

                Container container = null;
                try
                {
                    container = database.GetContainer("xxx");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while trying to get the container.");
                    return StatusCode(500, "An error occurred while trying to get the container.");
                }
                PartitionKey? pk = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(forecast.PartitionKey))
                {
                    pk = new PartitionKey(forecast.PartitionKey);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogError("The partition key cannot be null or empty.");
                    return BadRequest("The partition key cannot be null or empty.");
                }

                // Add the item to the container
                ItemResponse<WeatherForecast> response = await container.UpsertItemAsync<WeatherForecast>(forecast, pk);

                // Return the status code
                return new StatusCodeResult((int)response.StatusCode);
            }
            catch (CosmosException ex)
            {
                // Log the Cosmos DB exception
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"Cosmos DB Error. Status Code: {ex.StatusCode}, Substatus Code: {ex.SubStatusCode}, Message: {ex.Message}");
                return StatusCode(500, $"Cosmos DB Error. Status Code: {ex.StatusCode}, Substatus Code: {ex.SubStatusCode}, Message: {ex.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the general exception
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while trying to add an item to the Cosmos DB container.");
                return StatusCode(500, "An error occurred while trying to add an item to the Cosmos DB container.");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        [Authorize]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }

    }
}
```

Of the many things I've tried, I believe this one should work but I didn't manage to make it work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android